# BOOL being set to 'NO' but succeeds for a check off == YES

Tags: objective-c, ios

.h

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL dontSendDelegate;
```

.m

```
@synthesize dontSendDelegate;

- (id) initWithSession:(AVCaptureSession *)aSession outputFileURL:(NSURL 
*)anOutputFileURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        self.dontSendDelegate = NO;
    }
return self;
}


if (self.dontSendDelegate == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Thats all my code in that class relating to the BOOL.

It always prints YES.

What is it that I'm not understanding? I expect it to always print NO.

EDIT

Used Xcode to search 'dontSendDelegate'

It only appears in the code I've shown. Which is copy and paste.

Changed it to an int and assigned 0 instead of the 'NO' and did the comparison == 1 instead of == YES and it works as you would expect. But I'm still lost as to why BOOL was not working.

Thanks for all the help and discussion about the problem.

Comment: Looks like it was changed in the mean-time. You could just implement the setter your-self and check when it is called with `YES`.

Comment: Some bad memory management through which you overwrite `BOOL dontSendDelegate`? A multithreading issue? Try to prepend the ivar with the `volatile` keyword. Or else, you need to share more code.

Comment: @mvds: Memory management?  If the property was nil, it would log nil or 0 (NO) anyways.  You can't release static types like BOOL's though, so the OP is totally setting his property somewhere else.

Comment: Note that BOOL properties are set to NO, but instance variables have undefined behaviour. So you don't need to explicitly set to NO.

Comment: @Aram: ivars are initialized to zero, i.e. `NO` for `BOOL` ivars.

Comment: @CodaFi: yes, memory management. ivars are basically just entries in a struct with no enforcement of anything, so if you mess up really bad, you can accidentally overwrite ivars. Try putting a `char dumb[8];` before some other ivars and write 100 bytes to it. Mayhem! Countless other scenarios are possible.

Comment: @CodeFi: or, more realistically, passing a `&char_ivar` to some function wanting an `int*`, or worse, a `CGRect*`. etc etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the mutable part of an expression (your bool instance variable) before a comparison operator such as ==, sometimes you have a typo where you write = instead, so you set the variable instead of compare it. Look for errors of this type.

Or always put the immutable value first, so in the code you have provided so far you would instead write

```
if (YES == self.dontSendDelegate)
```

That way, if you ever type one equal sign instead of two, the compiler will complain.

(from comments) When testing boolean variables, you don't need to use == at all.  Just use `if (self.dontSendDelegate)` or `if (!self.dontSendDelegate)`.

Comment: As far as I've seen, Xcode will complain just the same the other way around, but I see this would be handy.

Comment: Since it's a boolean, you may as well write `if (self.dontSendDelegate)`.

Answer (score 0):

@GeorgFritzsche is correct. When this happens I override the setter and create a breakpoint. Then take a look at the stack on the left side of your screen and trace it down to the culprit. Most likely you are changing the value somewhere else in your program.